# XMVector3Project unexpected behaviour

Tags: directx-11

I'm trying to figure out World space to Screen space transform. As I understand, in D3D11, function XMVector3Project should handle this. However, when I use it like this:

```
XMVECTOR eye = XMVectorSet(10000, 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR at = XMVectorSet(10000, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);



auto viewMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixLookAtRH(eye2, at2, up2));
XMVECTOR vec = XMVector3Project(XMVectorSet(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0f), 0, 0, 480, 800, 0, 1, XMMatrixIdentity(), viewMatrix, XMMatrixIdentity());
```

it returns point (240, 480). I don't understand how that's possible, cause even with no Projection matrix, when I set view matrix to show point (1000, 1000, x), Point (0,0,0) shouldn't show on screen at all. 
That's just my view, probably wrong, so I would like to know how is that intended behaviour?

Comment: ``auto viewMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixLookAtRH(eye2, at2, up2));`` is your question missing the values for eye2, at2, up2? Also, why are you calling XMMatrixTranspose on the LookAt matrix? That is going to result in some strange behavior since it's not purely a rotation...

Comment: You should add the tag "directxmath" to this one...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is your use of `XMMatrixTranspose`. [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) (aka XNAMath version 3 aka xboxmath) functions are all written assuming you have row-major matrices either left-handed or right-handed. By applying the `XMMatrixTranspose` to the lookat matrix, you are making it column-major. While this is commonly done as a last step before setting it into a Constant Buffer for consumption by HLSL (see [MSDN DirectXMath Programmer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729728.aspx) and [MSDN HLSL docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634.aspx#Matrix_Ordering) for details), the result doesn't make sense to use this way with `XMVector3Project`.

BTW, I'm assuming your use of `XMVectorSet` here is just for testing, but the efficient way to code a constant XMVECTOR is using XMVECTORF32.

```
static const XMVECTORF32 eye = { 10000, 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f };
static const XMVECTORF32 at = { 10000, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
static const XMVECTORF32 up = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```